# Fill part of background color in Textbox C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

How can I Fill part of background color in Textbox C# Winforms.
Like this (this example create in Photoshop):

[image]

Can anyone help me...

Comment: Can build a custom control (User control)

Comment: I don't know how fill part of background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase and set color left border width in

> Edit UI Elements > BorderPrimitive > Box

but be carefull that

> set BoxStyle to FourBorders

Answer (score 3):

You should handle the [Paint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint%28v=vs.90%29.ASPX) event, then perform your custom drawing in the event handler.

Comment: No paint event with text box.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use panels. Paint the background of the panels the color of your liking. Place them on top of each other. Or you could use a picture as background.

Answer (score 0):

Crate a custom control, use group box with border, set its background, place a text box in it, set its border to none. You can  create same as you wish.

Comment: I'm looking for setting in textbox

Answer (score 0):

In the Properties of the textbox you can change the backcolor under the following setting. http://prntscr.com/3hjyhl